# NHibernate Linq cannot call a regular method that returns an IQueryable<T>

Tags: .net, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have the following query:

```
public ICollection<AccountAbsence> GetAccountAbsencesByRosters(WorkRoster[] workRosters)
{
    var processedWorkRosters = from workRoster in workRosters
                               select new WorkRoster
                               {
                                   Start = DateUtil.SyncToCrmTime(workRoster.Start),
                                   End = DateUtil.SyncToCrmTime(workRoster.End),
                                   ServicePlan = workRoster.ServicePlan
                               };

    return (from absence in GetNonCanceledAbsencesCriteria()
            where processedWorkRosters.Any(workRoster => workRoster.ServicePlan.Account.Id == absence.Account.Id && ((absence.End.HasValue && absence.End > workRoster.Start && absence.Start < workRoster.End) || (!absence.End.HasValue && absence.Start <= workRoster.End)))
            select absence).ToList();

}

    private IQueryable<AccountAbsence> GetNonCanceledAbsencesCriteria()
    {
        return ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<AccountAbsence>().AsQueryable()
                                    .Where(absence => absence.CancelDate == null || absence.CancelReason == null);
    }
```

And for some reason GetNonCanceledAbsencesCriteria() cannot be evaluated.
Here's the exception I am getting:

```
Message: Specified method is not supported.
Stack Trace:    at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.GetClassName(IASTNode querySource)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.Process(IASTNode tree)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.AstPolymorphicProcessor.Process()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.AstPolymorphicProcessor.Process(IASTNode ast
ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast
String queryIdentifier
String collectionRole
Boolean shallow
IDictionary`2 filters
ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier
IQueryExpression queryExpression
String collectionRole
Boolean shallow
IDictionary`2 filters
ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr
IQueryExpression queryExpression
String collectionRole
Boolean shallow
IDictionary`2 enabledFilters
ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr
IQueryExpression queryExpression
String collectionRole
Boolean shallow
IDictionary`2 enabledFilters
ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr
IQueryExpression queryExpression
Boolean shallow
IDictionary`2 enabledFilters
ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression
Boolean shallow
IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression
Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression
IQuery& query
NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.DataServices.AccountAbsenceDataService.GetAccountAbsencesByRosters(WorkRoster[] workRosters) in D:\Work\DanelNursing\branches\AugustVersion\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions\DataServices\AccountAbsenceDataService.cs:line 102
   at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.Validators.AccountAbsenceWorkRostersValidator.GetFailedWorkRosters() in D:\Work\DanelNursing\branches\AugustVersion\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions\Validators\AccountAbsenceWorkRostersValidator.cs:line 50
   at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.Generators.WorkingJournalsDataGenerator.generateLists(Branch branch
Int32 month
Int32 year) in D:\Work\DanelNursing\branches\AugustVersion\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions\Generators\WorkingJournalsDataGenerator.cs:line 412
   at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions.Generators.WorkingJournalsDataGenerator.Generate(Branch branch
Int32 month
Int32 year) in D:\Work\DanelNursing\branches\AugustVersion\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Actions\Generators\WorkingJournalsDataGenerator.cs:line 108
   at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Controllers.WorkingJournalsController.<>c__DisplayClass37.<ShowWorkingJournalsData>b__32() in D:\Work\DanelNursing\branches\AugustVersion\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling\Controllers\WorkingJournalsController.cs:line 826
   at Danel.Nursing.Scheduling.Viewlets.WaitForAction.Worker_DoWork(Object sender
DoWorkEventArgs e) in D:\Work\DanelNursing\branches\AugustVersion\Scheduling\Danel.Nursing.Scheduling\Viewlets\WaitForAction.cs:line 40
```

It seems like the LINQ provider should be able to figure this out.
Am I missing something here or is it not implemented?
EDIT:
It seems I was wrong and that processedWorkRosters.Any() cannot be evaluated.
How am I supposed to compare with an external array than?

Comment: Can you please try storing GetNonCanceledAbsencesCriteria() to a local variable and then using that variable in your LINQ query instead.

Comment: @degorolls Tried that. Same results. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `GetNonCanceledAbsencesCriteria()` returns an IQueryable, which conmes from the NH provider, which means any operation you perform on it is more than highly likely to get interpreted into SQL speak.

```
from absence in GetNonCanceledAbsencesCriteria()
where processedWorkRosters.Any( ... )
select absence
```

The problem with the above is that `processedWorkRosters` is a variable foreign to the NH Linq provider, which means it doesn't know how to translate them into sql speak.

Try:

```
from absence in GetNonCanceledAbsencesCriteria().ToArray()
where processedWorkRosters.Any( ... )
select absence
```

The `ToArray()` forces the `GetNonCanceledAbsencesCriteria()` to be evaluated immediately, but may be suboptimal (or not) ... and if is you may need to re-write the where clause to "close-to" SQL speak.

Comment: This is extremely sub-optimal in this case.

Comment: I'm accepting this as this is the correct answer, although I am not happy with it.